# jQuery next selector not working, syntax adjustment for accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, accordion, show-hide

I have an accordion on each page but only want the toggle-container open that applies to the category that page is in, the rest to be shut. I've been working on research for 2 hours and can't figure it out.

This is what I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle-container:not(#commercial:next.toggle_container").hide();
    $("#commercial").addClass("active").children().show();
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $(".toggle_container:visible").slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

css:

```
.toggle_container {
    display: none;
}
```

html snippet:

```
<div class="accordian">
  <h3 id="rack-structures" class="trigger"><a href="#">Rack Structures</a></h3>
  <div class="toggle_container">
    <div class="block">
      <p><a href="HEB-grocery-rack-structure-steel-contractor.html?panel=4"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />H-E-B Corporation</a></p>
      <p> <strong>Location:</strong> San Antonio TX</p>
      <p> Midwest Steel has great experience with specialized rack structure projects. This project was for a very large grocery chain serving the state of Texas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  tab entry  -->
  <div class="accordian">
    <h3 id="commercial" class="trigger"><a href="#">Commercial</a></h3>
    <div class="toggle_container">
      <div class="block">
        <p><a href="commercial-high-rise-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=5"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />Hyatt Corporation World Headquarters<br />
          Chicago, IL</a></p>
        <p><a href="hotel-casino-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=5"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />MGM Grand Hotel Casino<br />
          Detroit, MI</a></p>
        <p><a href="convention-center-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=5"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />Cobo Center<br />
          Detroit, MI</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  tab entry  -->
  <div class="accordian">
    <h3 id="airport-aerospace" class="trigger"><a href="#">Airport/Aerospace</a></h3>
    <div class="toggle_container">
      <div class="block">
        <p><a href="airport-terminal-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=6"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />NASA Moblie Launcher<br />
          Kennedy Space Center, FL</a></p>
        <p><a href="airport-terminal-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=6"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />Detroit Metropolitan Airport North Terminal Expansion<br />
          Romulus, MI</a></p>
        <p><a href="airport-structural-steel-contractor.html?panel=6"><img src="../images/1projects/mwsteel.jpg" width="930" height="270" alt="industrial steel" />Wichita Mid-Continent Airport <br />
          Wichita, KS</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line contain an error :

```
$(".toggle-container:not(#commercial:next.toggle_container").hide();
```

Checked the console, it was right there. Change it for that :

```
$(".toggle-container:not(#commercial + .toggle_container)").hide();
```

Comment: oops, there was an error i see, BUT the code above doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a closing parenthesis in this line:

```
$(".toggle-container:not(#commercial:next.toggle_container").hide();
```

Should be:

```
$(".toggle-container:not(#commercial:next.toggle_container)").hide();
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DC7g/)

Comment: Try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7DC7g/1/ "jSFiddle #2").  Is this what you're looking for?